# PHP Send mail function. How to make one email address receive one email containing data based on the number of ticked checkbox in a table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a send mail function of my system. I have a table that shows the data from my database. The send mail function of my system goes like this:

[image]

The user should fill up the form containing: Person in charge (email address), Comments and Status (Open or Closed) then tick the checkbox in the table. And all values in that row will be sent to the Person in charge. It is successfully working. What I want to do now is if I ticked 2 checkbox and I have the same person in charge, instead of receiving two emails, I want to make it one email, containing data according to number of ticked checkbox. For example I ticked 2 checkbox that will be send to emailadd@yahoo.com. How will I able to do it?:

**UPDATE:**

**I will explain it more coz I think my question is too complex. What I want is if one email address is receiver of multiple issue, instead of receiving it one email per issue, those issues will be put together in one email. so the receiver will only read it in one email.**

[image]

```
function InsertEmailMessage() {

    $explode_check=explode(',', $_POST['ticked']);
    //print_r($explode_check); 
    for($i=0;$i<count($explode_check);$i++)
    {
        $Selcheckb=$explode_check[$i];

        $sql6 = "SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice WHERE ID='".$Selcheckb."'";
        $conn = dbConnect();
        $stmt6 = $conn->prepare($sql6); 
        //$stmt6->bindParam(':id6', $_POST['idtxt'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt6->execute();
        $data = $stmt6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //var_dump($data);    

        foreach ($data as $row6) {

            $invnumb=$row6['Invoice_Number'];
            $partnumb=$row6['Part_Number'];
            $issue=$row6['Issues'];
            $pic=$row6['PIC_Comments'];
            $emailadd= $row6['PersoninCharge'];
            $issuetype=$row6['Issue_Type'];
            $createdate=$row6['Creation_Date'];
            $site=$row6['Site'];
            $vendor=$row6['Vendor_Name'];
            $invdate=$row6['Invoice_Date'];
            $po=$row6['PO'];
            $rr=$row6['RR']; 
            $currency=$row6['Currency'];
            $invamount=$row6['Invoice_Amount'];
            $stat=$row6['Status'];


            if($row6['Status']=="Open") {


                $message = "<html><b>Issue Type: {$issuetype} </b><br><br>";       
                $message .= "<b>Creation Date: {$createdate} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>Site: {$site} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>Vendor Name: {$vendor} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>Invoice Date: {$invdate} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>Invoice Number: {$invnumb} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>Part Number:</b><br>{$partnumb}<br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>PO: {$po} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>RR: {$rr} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>Currency: {$currency} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>Invoice Amount: {$invamount} </b><br><br>";
                $message .= "<b>Issues:</b><br>{$issue}<br>";
                $message .= "<b>Status: {$stat} </b><br><br>";  
                $message .= "<b>{$pic}<b><br>";  
                $message .= "</html>";

            }

            if(!empty($emailadd)) {
                dbInsertEmailMessage($emailadd, "Invoice Number: {$invnumb} - {$issue}.", $message);
                echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email sent to {$emailadd}.')</script>";
            }

        }
    }

    $conn=null;
}



function dbInsertEmailMessage($send_to, $subject, $message) {

    $sql7 = "INSERT INTO email_queue (send_to, subject, message) VALUES (:send_to, :subject, :message)";    
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $stmt7 = $conn->prepare($sql7); 
    $stmt7->bindParam(':send_to', $send_to);
    $stmt7->bindParam(':subject', $subject);
    $stmt7->bindParam(':message', $message);
    $stmt7->execute();
    $conn=null; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move some stuff around. Instead of sending in the foreach loop just build up an array of $messages keyed with with email address. After all messages are built then loop the messages and send.

Also, your code is open to SQL Injection which allows anyone to run any query they want. You were on the right track with `->bindParam` method of PDO.

Here is the code:

```
function InsertEmailMessage() {
    $explode_check=explode(',', $_POST['ticked']);
    //print_r($explode_check);

    $messages = array();

    for($i=0;$i<count($explode_check);$i++)
    {
        $Selcheckb=$explode_check[$i];

        $conn = dbConnect();
        $stmt6 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice WHERE ID=:cb");
        $stmt6->bindParam(':cb', $Selcheckb);
        $stmt6->execute();
        $data = $stmt6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //var_dump($data);

        foreach ($data as $row6) {

            $invnumb=$row6['Invoice_Number'];
            $partnumb=$row6['Part_Number'];
            $issue=$row6['Issues'];
            $pic=$row6['PIC_Comments'];
            $emailadd= $row6['PersoninCharge'];
            $issuetype=$row6['Issue_Type'];
            $createdate=$row6['Creation_Date'];
            $site=$row6['Site'];
            $vendor=$row6['Vendor_Name'];
            $invdate=$row6['Invoice_Date'];
            $po=$row6['PO'];
            $rr=$row6['RR'];
            $currency=$row6['Currency'];
            $invamount=$row6['Invoice_Amount'];
            $stat=$row6['Status'];

            if($row6['Status']=="Open") {
                if(!isset($messages[$emailadd])) {
                  $messages[$emailadd] = '';
                }

                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Issue Type: {$issuetype} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Creation Date: {$createdate} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Site: {$site} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Vendor Name: {$vendor} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Date: {$invdate} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Number: {$invnumb} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Part Number:</b><br>{$partnumb}<br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>PO: {$po} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>RR: {$rr} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Currency: {$currency} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Amount: {$invamount} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Issues:</b><br>{$issue}<br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Status: {$stat} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>{$pic}<b><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($messages as $email=>$message) {
        dbInsertEmailMessage($email, "Invoice Number: {$invnumb} - {$issue}.", "<html>{$message}</html>");
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email sent to {$email}.')</script>";
    }

    $conn=null;
}

function dbInsertEmailMessage($send_to, $subject, $message) {
    $sql7 = "INSERT INTO email_queue (send_to, subject, message) VALUES (:send_to, :subject, :message)";
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $stmt7 = $conn->prepare($sql7);
    $stmt7->bindParam(':send_to', $send_to);
    $stmt7->bindParam(':subject', $subject);
    $stmt7->bindParam(':message', $message);
    $stmt7->execute();
    $conn=null;
}
```

Comment: I will explain it more coz I think my question is too complex. What I want is if one email address is receiver of multiple issue, instead of receiving it one email per issue, those issues will be put together in one email. so the receiver will only read it in one email.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I was not sure what to do with the subject `{$invnumb}  - {$issue}` as it seems there may be more than one value. You might just want to remove those values from the subject and use something generic since the data is in the message.

Comment: is it supposedly (foreach($messages as $email=>$message) instead of (foreach(messages as $email=>$message)???

Comment: I tried your code but data is not inserting in the database.

Comment: Yes, sorry.. Using my python IDE to write php so I did not catch that. It should actually be `foreach($messages as $email=>$message)`. I will update the answer with the right code.

Comment: Try again, I also forget the `$` in front of `messages` and I had to move `$messages = array()` outside the first loop too.

Comment: It's now inserting in the database but it only saved the second checkbox I ticked.

Comment: My pleasure. Please note that in the latest code I used `$stmt6->bindParam(':cb', $Selcheckb);` as the previous code was open to a nasty hack called sql injection.

Comment: Oh ok. noted on that. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Hi what if I have multiple email address?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple email addresses? Where would the multiple emails be (what variable)?

Comment: In the Person in charge textbox. If I will put more than one email in sending the data based on the checkbox ticked

Comment: How will I do it, if I want to send the email to multiple email address?

Comment: Your code does nothing with the textbox addresses, it pulls the email address from the database. Since there is no way to know what invoices to send to emails from the text box you can send all invoices to all email addresses. After `foreach($messages as $email=>$message)` you can combine all $messages, split the email addresses on comma and loop those sending a message to each. You should try coding it yourself first.

Comment: Thanks I will try to do that

Comment: After the foreach($messages as $email=>$message)? or inside?

Comment: After the foreach. You will basically send a message to emails in the database then the list of user supplied email addresses.